# Working with ADO.net and special characters in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I want to write a small application in Winforms, where I will be able to write some words and write them to a SQL database using ADO.net.

I'm having trouble when I want to write a string with a placeholder like:

```
Give me your '%s' right now!
```

What is recorded in my DB is:

```
Give me your **"%s"** right now!
```

How can I overcome this be changing the string via C# that is transferred to my DB?

This is part of my code:

```
 public virtual int Split(global::System.Nullable<int> ID, object SplitXMLDoc, string CreatedBy)
 {
            global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = this.CommandCollection[4];
            if ((ID.HasValue == true)) {
                command.Parameters[1].Value = ((int)(ID.Value));
            }
            else {
                command.Parameters[1].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            if ((SplitXMLDoc == null)) {
                command.Parameters[2].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                command.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)(SplitXMLDoc));
            }
            if ((CreatedBy == null)) {
                command.Parameters[3].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                command.Parameters[3].Value = ((string)(CreatedBy));
            }
            global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = command.Connection.State;
            if (((command.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                        != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
                command.Connection.Open();
            }
            int returnValue;
            try {
                returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally {
                if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed))
 {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: Could u please clarify what you're trying to achieve? What's not working? Do you need to compare string that has single quotes to a string that has double quotes in a WHERE clause?

Comment: I want to write and read words from my database exectaly the way I first wrote them in my app. I don't understand why 'a' becomes "a" and do on.

Comment: Can you please post code - how you insert text into DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use parameterized sql.

```
string val = "'%s'".Replace("'","\"");
string sql = "INSERT Into Table1 (value) values (@Value)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value",val);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```