# C# dbase IV read special characters

Tags: c#, database-connection, special-characters, dbf, dbase

this is my first post and I want to thank you everybody for years of help. It's the first time ever, that I use a forum and I think, this one here is the best. So now enough of that :-)  I have the following code:

```
public void ConnectToDBF(string pathToFile, string fileName)
     {
         string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathToFile + ";Extended Properties=\"dBASE IV;CharacterSet=1251;IMEX=1\"";
         using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
         {
             var sql = "select * from " + fileName;
             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
             con.Open();
             DataSet dsMyDbfFile = new DataSet(); ;
             OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
             da.Fill(dsMyDbfFile);
             con.Close();

             DataRow drMyDbfFile = dsMyDbfFile.Tables[0].Rows[0];
             string test = drMyDbfFile[0].ToString();

             Encoding wind1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
             Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
             byte[] wind1251Bytes = wind1251.GetBytes(drMyDbfFile[5].ToString());
             byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1251, utf8, wind1251Bytes);
             string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

         }
```

I tried to get some Data from a dbf file and it works fine. But when there are special characters in it, like ä, ö, é or somthing like that, then I only get a question mark or other confusing characters. I tried to add the charset directly to the connectionstring, but without success. Then I tried to convert it afterwards, but it still does not work. I really don't know, where the error is and I hope, anybody of you can help me. Kind Regards!

Comment: Why all those encoding conversions? If you execute `drMyDbfFile[5].ToString()` that will implicitly apply an encoding, isn't it correct?.

Comment: yes, it will just encode column 5 of the current row. In my prod, it is a loop through the whole DB File. But the encoding doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should use [] brackets in fileName

See this proplem

[how-to-access-an-column-with-special-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081523/how-to-access-an-column-with-special-characters-using-datatable-select)

or
[insert into sql db a string that contain special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867729/insert-into-sql-db-a-string-that-contain-special-character)

or
[Working with ADO.net and special characters in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197778/working-with-ado-net-and-special-characters-in-sql)

Comment: Do you mean brackets instead of * or around the fileName variable? So far, I tried it around the fileName var, but it didn't work. There is still a ? instead of the special char